# How to convert a ndarray to a structured array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a regular float ndarray with shape `(100,50)`. How can I give names to the first two columns, i.e. `'idx1'` and `'idx2'`, and `'data'` to the rest of the columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `view` method.  Here's an example, using an array with shape (3, 5) for the demo:

```
In [21]: x
Out[21]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.]])

In [22]: y = x.ravel().view(dtype=[('idx1', float), ('idx2', float), ('data', float, 3)])

In [23]: y['idx1']
Out[23]: array([  0.,   5.,  10.])

In [24]: y['data']
Out[24]: 
array([[  2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  7.,   8.,   9.],
       [ 12.,  13.,  14.]])

In [25]: y['data'][1]
Out[25]: array([ 7.,  8.,  9.])
```

Note that `y` is a 1-D array; it has shape (3,).  If you change the conversion to `y = x.view(...)` (i.e. don't ravel `x`), `y` will have have (3,1), and `y['idx1']` will have shape (3,1).

Comment: Nice, didn't know about using `ravel` to avoid the extra length-1 axis.